# Autofac Generic Multiple Interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am trying to resolve one generic interface something like below but I am getting exception when trying to run the application .

```
public interface IHandler<in T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T args);
}

public class ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler : IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(ApplicationUserCreatedEvent args)
    {
        if (args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("args");
        // Code 
    }
}
```

I am registering in global.asax like below

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler>().As(typeof (IHandler<>));
    return builder.Build();
}
```

This is how I am resolving the dependency using IComponentContext .

```
var handlers = _componentContext.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<TEvent>>>();
```

So When I am trying to run this code it gives me below error .

> The type 'Service.ActionService.DomainEventHandler.ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler'
>   is not assignable to service 'Domain.Core.DomainEvent.IHandler`1'.

I am not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be resolving `_componentContext.Resolve<IHandler<TEvent>>();` without the IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to register `ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler` as an open type of `IHandler<>` but this type is not a `IHandler<>` it is a `IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>` so you have to register it as it.

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler>()
       .As(typeof(IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>));
```

And you will be able to resolve it this way :

```
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>>>();
```

By the way, if you want to register an open type you can use something like this :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler<TUserCreatedEvent>))
       .As(typeof(IHandler<>));
```

and `ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler<T>` like this :

```
public class ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler<TUserCreatedEvent>
    : IHandler<TUserCreatedEvent>
    where TUserCreatedEvent : ApplicationUserCreatedEvent
{
    public void Handle(TUserCreatedEvent args)
    {
        if (args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("args");
        // Code 
    }
}
```

And you will still be able to resolve it this way :

```
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>>>();
```

Comment: I am trying to resolve multiple event handlers . In my case it's not resolving my implementations . I think I am doing something wrong . I am following your first approach like this . var handlers = _componentContext.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<IDomainEvent>>>(); In my boot straper class builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler>().As(typeof(IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>)); I am passing IDomainEvent interface instaed of concrete implementation as I am trying to resolve all implementing IDomainEvent

Comment: `ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler` is not convertible to `IHandler<IDomainEvent>`. To allow this kind of conversion you have to convert your type to a covariant type which is not possible because you have a method that accept T as a parameter.

Comment: BTW why would you need all your events and not only events for a specific `T` ? another common solution for this kind of problem is to have a non generic base interface for `IHandler`.

Comment: I need to capture all my event handlers implementing IHandler<IDomainEvent> some thing like this public class ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler : IHandler<ApplicationUserCreatedEvent>. I will try non generic approach as well  .

Comment: non generic solution worked for me like this public interface IHandler
    {
        void Handle(IDomainEvent args);
    } . But it would be nice if I can resolve the generic solution using Autofac  .

Comment: forget about *Autofac* and try to do what you want with hard coded dependencies. I don't think it is possible without a base class. `IEnumerable<IHandler<IDomainEvent>> = new IHandler<IDomainEvent>[] {  new ApplicationUserCreatedEventHandler()}` won't work at runtime. By the way, if you really want we can find a way to have a IEnumerable<Object> but what will you do with this array ?

Comment: Thank You . I am also thinking the same way to remove autofac . Initial idea was like to register all classes implementing IHandler present in the assembly in one shot in stead of registering one by one and resolve all of them in one line as well . using structure map IOC container it works pretty well . I mean with out concrete implementation .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76604/discussion-between-cyril-durand-and-user2009755).